# Term for an equation which is not a differential equation?

Tags: terminology, systems-of-equations

I am wondering if there is a name for a system of equations of the form: 
$$
f_j\left(x_{1},\dots,x_{n}\right)=0
$$
with $1 \leq j \leq m$ for some $m\in\mathbb{N}$ and where the $x_i$ are unknown numbers and we wish to solve for them.
Basically the most general system of equations which is an equation for finding unknown numbers. What I want is a term to contrast this with a system of differential equations. I thought that this is called a "system of algebraic equations" but apparently the term "algebraic equation" means the case where $f$ is a polynomial.

Comment: It is just a system of equations if you don't require more.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_equation  maybe ?

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee: not at all. A functional equation is one where the unknown is a function.

Comment: If you want to stress "non-differentialness", you may say an *ordinary system of equations*. (With the risk of people reading an *ordinary differential equation* - ODE). IMO, a *system of ordinary equations* would be puzzling.